# Stackmob SMQuery OR conditioning: "Sort cannot be used with OR statements stackmob"

Tags: stackmob

I am using Stackmob SMQuery and trying to have a Query with 4 OR conditions and sort all the results after all. My code is as below. The problem is

```
        SMQuery *query = [[SMQuery alloc] initWithSchema:STACKMOB_SCHEMA_TESTIMONIAL];

        [query where:@"friend_id" isIn:[friendFacebookIds arrayByAddingObject:[KKKeychain getStringForKey:@"facebookId"]]];

        // WHERE (privacy == Public OR (privacy == Private AND friend_id == myFacebookId) OR (privacy == Restricted AND myFacebookId NOT IN restricted_Ids))

        SMQuery *subQuery0 = [[SMQuery alloc] initWithSchema:STACKMOB_SCHEMA_TESTIMONIAL];
        SMQuery *subQuery1 = [[SMQuery alloc] initWithSchema:STACKMOB_SCHEMA_TESTIMONIAL];
        SMQuery *subQuery2 = [[SMQuery alloc] initWithSchema:STACKMOB_SCHEMA_TESTIMONIAL];
        SMQuery *subQuery3 = [[SMQuery alloc] initWithSchema:STACKMOB_SCHEMA_TESTIMONIAL];

        [subQuery0 where:@"privacy" isEqualTo:nil]; // just in case no privacy was set, assume it is public
        [subQuery0 orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];

        [subQuery1 where:@"privacy" isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TTPrivacyLevelPublic]];
        [subQuery1 orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];

        [subQuery2 where:@"privacy" isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TTPrivacyLevelPrivate]];
        [subQuery2 where:@"user_id" isEqualTo:[KKKeychain getStringForKey:@"facebookId"]]; // for private post, I can only see posts that were created by me
        [subQuery2 orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];

        [subQuery3 where:@"privacy" isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TTPrivacyLevelRestricted]];
        [subQuery3 where:@"restricted_user_ids" isNotEqualTo:[KKKeychain getStringForKey:@"facebookId"]]; // make sure I'm not restricted to see
        [subQuery3 orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];

        // combine subquery to main query

        [query and:[[[subQuery1 or:subQuery2] or:subQuery3] or:subQuery0]];

        [query orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];
        ....
```

So if I commented the last line "[query orderByField:@"createddate" ascending:NO];" then it works fine. But then the results will be a combination of 4 different dataset which is not sorted in createdate order. I also tried to sort in each subquery but the result was also incorrect because they are only sorted inside each subquery, not combining with other results as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't support executing a query that includes both OR and sorting - this is a database limitation. Instead, perform the query on StackMob, then locally sort the results by createddate using sortedArrayUsingComparator or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. Btw Stackmob is shut down. End of story.